# git commit with gpg key does not work from VSCode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, gnupg, gpg-agent

Added a gpg key to sign commits.

After all the configuration is done, I am able to sign via git cli.

But when I commit using vscode it opens a terminal window so I can enter my key password.
The window appears a little buggy and does not accept the password and returns the error in vscode:

```
error: gpg failed to sign the data
```

When I restart gpg-agent and manage to commit via cli.

When I type the password through the cli, it is stored in that section of the terminal and I manage to commit through vscode. When you close the section, the error returns.

I'm using wsl2 with linux Ubuntu 20

Comment: sorry, i`m fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution...

Steps required:

Install GPG4Win from https://www.gpg4win.org. Nothing other than the default gnupg is required, but I installed Kleopatra too in case it came in handy elsewhere.

Edit ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf and change the pinentry

pinentry-program "/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/GnuPG/bin/pinentry-basic.exe"

Answer (score 0):

I guess your issue is :

- you started VSCode from an environment where the gpg-agent wasn't started, and hence VSCode doesn't have access to the environment variables that indicate how to access the gpg-agent
- when you start the gpg-agent from a terminal opened in VSCode, it updates the environment for *that terminal* (each terminal is a separate process) but not for the IDE or other terminals

---

To confirm that having the correct environment works, you can try the following :

- close all running instances of VSCode
- open a fresh terminal (whatever shell you use: bash, powershell, cmd.exe ...)
- from that terminal, start your gpg-agent
- from that same terminal, launch VSCode from the command line
- check if you still have issues committing from that instance of VSCode

You can check the environment before and after starting your gpg-agent to confirm that variables do get updated (in bash, this simply means running `env` or `env | sort` from the command line).

Comment: Yes, ! would like to start gpg-agent together with vscode

Answer (score 0):

Also, when using gitconfig files to enable GPG signing, make sure to use the long key from when you created your gpg key i.e.:

```
[user]
email = example@email.com
name = My Name
signingkey = ########################################
[gpg]
    program = gpg
[commit]
    gpgsign = true
```

Which should work if you get errors like not being able to sign because a private key does not exist.

If you want to find out these credentials, go to git bash and hit the `gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format=long`  command which should output something along the lines of:

```
sec   rsa4096/SHORT_KEY_ID yyyy-mm-dd [SC] [expires: yyyy-mm-dd]
  LONG_KEY_ID
uid                 [ultimate] My Name (comment) <example@email.com>
ssb   rsa4096/SHORT_KEY_ID yyyy-mm-dd [E] [expires: yyyy-mm-dd]
```

You will want to use the LONG_KEY_ID for the signing key!

Hope that helps.

**Signed**, 9662e103-129a